# Is paper considered a tool?

Tags: discussion, tags

[I recently asked a question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/361/44) regarding the identification of paper without feeling it.

Is applying a tool-related tag to a paper-question within the scope of those tags?

Or is paper not considered a tool? (at least in origami)

Comment: It is usually a good idea to link to questions you are referring to so that people can link straight to them without having to look themselves. Unless you wanted to discuss a general topic and are trying to not single someone out. In this case you are talking about your own question so I set up the link for you.

Answer (score 3):

In this, and near all cases, paper should be considered a material and/or a medium. Tools are more for implements and machines. Paper isnt really either of those things.

I think [paper](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper) on its own is enough for your question as you are asking about paper specifically (As far as the scope of this Meta question is concerned). I don't *foresee* many [material-identification](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-identification) questions.

If your want to make a case for it I would suggest we try to come up with some more examples for its justification.

---

I think that question could use some work as well but that will be covered in the question itself.

Comment: I encourage you to wait for others to vote and answer before you take the word of a rambling pile of bagels.

Comment: +1. I'd consider paper the medium, and not a tool. And while origami doesn't _require_ tools, examples would be paper cutters, burnishers, bone folders, and tweezers (if you like doing microgami from 1cm squares).